# File type is empty string when uploading from Android native browser

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, file-upload

I have an `input(type="file")` on a web page.

```
<input type='file' name="file" accept="image/*" />
```

I use jQuery to grab the file like this:

```
$('input').on('change', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.files[0]);
});
```

I need to check if `e.target.files[0].type` matches `"image.*"` pattern, so I do:
`var matches = e.target.files[0].type.match('image.*');`

This works fine in most of the cases, but when the application is run from Android native browser, the `e.target.files[0].type` is empty string. This happens if I select an image stored on the device. If I take an image with camera `e.target.files[0].type` is `"image/jpeg"`.

Did anyone encounter this problem before?

Comment: Can you write fiddle? `files[0].type` generally provides file type accurately. Also check you have not chosen any invalid/corrupt file just in case.

Answer (score 0):

As I have added comment already, I tried to make use cases with below code snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Image Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="previewAndUploadFile(event)"/><br/>
    <img id="imagePreview" width="200" height="200"/>
    <div id="imageType"></div>
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function previewAndUploadFile(event) {
        var type = document.getElementById("imageType");
        var file = event.target.files[0];
        try {
            var reader = new FileReader()
            reader.onload = function() {
                var preview = document.getElementById("imagePreview");
                preview.src = reader.result;
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            type.innerHTML = file.type;
        } catch(e){
            type.innerHTML = "Invalid image.";
        }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

1. When the file name is `sample.jpeg` and image is valid image, all worked fine. The result was `image/jpeg`
2. When the file name is `sample` (removed the file extension but image content is still valid), the result was empty string.
3. When the image is corrupt (by editing it in notepad, you can try other ways) and file name was `sample.jpeg`, image type was still resulted as `image/jpeg`.
4. Repeated the case-3 with image renamed to `sample`, the image type resulted as empty string again.

May be your case was one of them.